# Max-height on empty div

Tags: html, css

I have DIV element which only has a few lines in and a background image.
The image size is 335px height.

I want the the div's max-height to be 335px but allow it to shrink if the browser window is smaller(mobile).

But the div just stays the size of the paragraph in the div. 
This is my CSS code for the DIV. Any ideas on how i can set the default starting height to 335px but allow it to shrink? The max width works perfectly.

```
#header
{
    background-image: url('Images/Header.png'); 
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:1024px; 
    max-height: 335px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    --max-line-height: 335px;
}
```

Many Thanks D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS -

```
#header{
    background-image: url('Images/Header.png');
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:1024px;
    height: 335px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

And for mobile devices use `CSS Media Queries`  http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

```
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 335px) {
 #header{
        height: auto;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dipaks, ive tried this, but then the div has a fixed height of 335px. I want the div to shrink according to the browser size

Comment: Then don't assign any height to it. It will automatically shrink

Comment: The problem is it does shrink to the 1 line of text in the DIV. I want it to default to 335px in height but only when the browser screen is smaller to adjust down.

Comment: Use height height: 335px; and the media queries. It should solve your problem

Comment: Hmm is my only option to use media queries? Can't what Ive suggested be done?

Comment: Media query will give you the simplest CSS solution, but you can go for jquery with some complicated screen resolution identifications. You decide.... because there isn't only one mobile device. There are many screen variations in devices too :)

Comment: @davey Check the media query I added.. there is not harm in using the CSS code. Why you don't want to use media query?

Comment: Media query is fine but you have to specify each screen size 1024px, 800px 480px etc say if shrunk it to 500px it would default to 800px.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-height: 335px` or `height: 335px`. so your `#header` css will be,

```
#header
{
    background-image: url('Images/Header.png'); 
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:1024px; 
    max-height: 335px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-height: 335px;    /* OR */  height: 335px;
    overflow: auto;
    --max-line-height: 335px;
}
```

Comment: min-height does not work, its does not default the height to 335px at start before the window is shrunk. The div shrinks straight away :(

Comment: but i want it to shrink below 335px if the window is smaller.